# css selector :nth-child(even|odd) vs :nth-child(int)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following issue with CSS `:nth-child` pseudo selector and I'm pretty sure I have missed something out.

**`index.html`**

```
<html>
<head>...</head>

    <body>

        <div class='selector'>first</div>
        <div class='selector'>second</div>
        <div class='selector'>third</div>
        <div class='selector'>fourth</div>
        <div class='selector'>fifth</div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**`style_does_not_work.css`** (does not work)

```
.selector { background-color: #ffffff; }
.selector:nth-child(1) { background-color: #f00000; }
.selector:nth-child(2) { background-color: #ff0000; }
.selector:nth-child(3) { background-color: #fff000; }
.selector:nth-child(4) { background-color: #ffff00; }
.selector:nth-child(5) { background-color: #fffff0; }
```

**`style_that_works.css`** (for the proof of the selector concept)

```
.selector { background-color: #ffffff; }
.selector:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f00000; }
.selector:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ff0000; }
```

I'm a little bit confused why `:nth-child(2)` does not work but `:nth-child(even)` does. Is there a difference or something I've missed out?

My goal is to give fixed positionned elements a dynamic offset from top while the elements are injected and removed by javascript dynamically.

**Update / Additional**

Unfortunately I've made a typo in the example above. But this unfortunately does not solve the real case - even I see the working JS-Fiddles (I'm really confused because of that...)

Additionally I've post some screens with the current issue:

[image: Markup Sample]

CSS:

```
.notification-area {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.notification-area.top-right {
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    left: auto;

    -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s, top 0.4s, left 0.4s, right 0.4s, bottom 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.4s, top 0.4s, left 0.4s, right 0.4s, bottom 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: margin 0.4s, top 0.4s, left 0.4s, right 0.4s, bottom 0.4s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.4s, top 0.4s, left 0.4s, right 0.4s, bottom 0.4s;
    transition: margin 0.4s, top 0.4s, left 0.4s, right 0.4s, bottom 0.4s;

}

/* these lines are completely ignored */

.notification-area:nth-child(2) { margin: 125px 0px 0px 0px; }
.notification-area:nth-child(3) { margin: 250px 0px 0px 0px; }
.notification-area:nth-child(4) { margin: 375px 0px 0px 0px; }
.notification-area:nth-child(5) { margin: 500px 0px 0px 0px; }


/* this line grabs instead - I don't want to use "even", but it shows me, that the selector :nth-child() should be fine... */
.notification-area:nth-child(even) { margin: 125px 0px 0px 0px; }
```

Comment: It *should* work correctly in this case. If anything, it's your `:nth-first-child` and `:nth-last-child` selectors that shouldn't work - because they're invalid.

Comment: There is a typo in your HTML - `<div class='selector'>second<div>` this div is not closed properly. Hence the error.

Comment: @Paulie_D thats a typo in the question, but not in the real case.

Comment: Looks like your code works fine to me - http://jsfiddle.net/x4ymrdkf/

Answer (score 7):

You didn't close `div` in second `.selector`. Works fine:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cn2nnaza/1/)

Comment: This was a typo while I've tried to write the example. At the real case it does not work either. I try to provide more samples.

Comment: @godesign so as mention above this should work expect `:nth-first-child` and `:nth-last-child` cause are wrong.

Comment: I've also expected that it works, thats why I'm so confused. Ive updated the question with a screenshot from the markup, where you can see the case. Where :nth-child(even|odd) works :nth-child(1,2,3,4...) does not grab.

Comment: If you have both selectors in your css like your css example in your OP then `even` one overwrites `:nthchild`. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/cn2nnaza/4/

Comment: well, I'm not using both together - I've changed them to test it side by side. I just figured out, that nth-child(2n|3n...) works as well (I know thats repeating but its the same selector)

Answer (score 1):

You missed closing tag of div in 2nd div.

Comment: the closing was an issue i've only made here in the example - I can assure its closed in the real case.

Comment: @godesign: Aside from that, the `nth-child` CSS in your question works fine. If you still have a problem, you've simplified away the problem in your real case while making the test case. Make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :nth-child(n+1) instead of :nth-child(2)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `nth-child(n)` to `nth-of-type(n)` since we're not working with their child nodes. I've deleted this answer before because I thought that the real problem was that you forgot to close one of your divs but you seem to haven't solve it yet so I'll post it again.